# Sending data from Main to Detail and Updating Object in MainViewMode

Tags: data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the following `recyclerview` where it contains list of `TestViewModel` objects. In this object I have `age`, `gender` and `name` properties. I am trying to achieve when user click on a list item, it takes user to detail view where user  could able to update and click on the save button, then it updates the selected item properties.

**Issue:**

The following piece of code  in `MainViewModel` where I receive the message from `DetailViewModel` works when user enter values in the detail and updating each property,

```
private void OnMessageReceived(TestMessage obj)
{
    _selectedItem.Age = obj.messageTest.Age;
    _selectedItem.Name = obj.messageTest.Name;
    _selectedItem.Gender = obj.messageTest.Gender;
}
```

but the following piece of code does not work where I am trying to update the object by itself directly.

```
private void OnMessageReceived(TestMessage obj)
{
    _selectedItem= obj.messageTest;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
}
```

**Code Implementation is as follows:**

```
<MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/TestRecyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource TestsViews; ; ItemClick ItemSelected" />
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public MainViewModel SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        ShowViewModel<DetailViewModel>(
        new DetailViewModel.Parameter
        {
            Age = _selectedItem.Age,
            Name = _selectedItem.Name,
            Gender = _selectedItem.Gender,
        });
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
    }
}

public virtual ICommand ItemSelected
{
   get
    {
      return new MvxCommand<TestViewModel>(item =>
      {
          SelectedItem = item;
      });
     }
}

private void OnMessageReceived(TestMessage obj)
{
    _selectedItem.Age= obj.messageTest.Age;
    _selectedItem.Name= obj.messageTest.Name;
    _selectedItem.Gender= obj.messageTest.Gender;
 }
```

**TestMessage**

```
public class TestMessage : MvxMessage
{
    public MainModel messageTest { get; set; }

    public TestMessage(object sender, MainModel editTest) : base(sender)
    {
        messageTest = editTest;
    }
}
```

**DetailViewModel**

```
public TestViewModel EditTest
{
    get { return _editTest; }
    set
    {
        _editTest = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => EditTest);
    }
}

public DetailViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger)
{
    _messenger = messenger;
}

public void Save()
{
    UpdateValues();
}

public void UpdateValues()
{
    var message = new TestMessage(this, _editTest);
    _messenger.Publish(message, typeof(TestMessage));
}

public void Init(Parameter param)
{
    _editTest = new TestViewModel();
    _editTest.Age = param.Age;
    _editTest.Name = param.Name;
    _editTest.Gender = param.Gender;

public class Parameter
{
    public double Age { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**DetailView xml**

```
<EditText
    style="@style/InputNumbersEditText"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:hint="00.000"
    local:MvxBind="Text EditTest.Age, Converter=Nullable;" />
```

**TestViewModel**

```
public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public double? Age { get; set; }
    public int? Gender { get; set; }
}
```

**NullableValueConverter**

```
public class NullableValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()))
        {
            return parameter;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `TestsViews` (the property of the MainViewModel) look like? What type has it?

Comment: I have just edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void OnMessageReceived(TestMessage obj)
{
    _selectedItem= obj.messageTest;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
}
```

This can't work, because your are just changing the reference of `_selectedItem` to point to another object. But this object is not included in the list that is used to show in the recycler view. You are **not** updating a object, just a reference! You should definitely have a look at the basics of C# to understand this kind of data structure. E.g. [Reference vs. Value Type](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm)

Your code is a bit faulty.

- You `SelectedItem` has the type `MainViewModel`
- Your click command gets a item of type `TestViewModel`

  ```
  public virtual ICommand ItemSelected
  {
      get
      {
          return new MvxCommand<TestViewModel>(item =>
          {
              SelectedItem = item;
          });
      }
  }
  ```

Normally this should work:

```
private void OnMessageReceived(TestMessage obj)
{
    _selectedItem.Age= obj.messageTest.Age;
    _selectedItem.Name= obj.messageTest.Name;
    _selectedItem.Gender= obj.messageTest.Gender;
}
```

but with a `TestViewModel` like

```
public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string? name;
    public string? Name { get{ return name; } set { SetProperty(ref name, value); } }
    // same for Age and Gender
}
```

`SetProperty` sets the value and calls the OnPropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Assigning the `_selectedItem` a new `TestViewModel` breaks the reference link it has to the `TestViewModel` held in the `TestsViews` data source list. While assigning the individual properties maintains the reference to the orginal `TestViewModel` in the `TestsViews` list.

**Orginal Answer**

As you are updating the backing field, `_selectedItem`, so when you receive the message event the `RaisePropertyChanged` event defined in the set of your `SelectedItem` property will never run. You will have to manually trigger the `RaisePropertyChanged` in order to trigger the binding update.

Try changing your current method:

```
private void OnMessageReceived(TestMessage obj)
{
    _selectedItem= obj.messageTest;
}
```

To raise the property changed event:

```
private void OnMessageReceived(TestMessage obj)
{
    _selectedItem = obj.messageTest;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: I think the issue maybe the assignment of the `TestMessage`'s `messageTest` (`TestViewModel`) property is a new object (has a different reference) and therefore when it gets assigned it is no longer able to update the `selectedItem` from the RecyclerView. This explains why it works when you assign individual properties as they are based on the `selectedItem` still linked to the RecyclerView.